# How to implement interchangeable/switchable business logic

Tags: c#, .net

Lets say I have 3 tasks: Registration, Assessment, Enrollment.

I want to be able to make my application have these 3 interchangeable in position in the process. So for one setting, I can do Registration -> Assessment -> Enrollment. I can change for another setting to Registration -> Enrollment -> Assessment.

And also I need to be able to switch on/off some functionality of task (like Registration).

Can you guys give me an idea of where to start?

Comment: Who decides the order of the tasks and whether to switch them on or off?

Comment: Interchangable means to me that the User gets to decide what's first, in that case just control enabling of the buttons to follow your rules.  Provide them with three buttons, Registration Assessment which will not enable Enrollment until both are ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set up a [chain of responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern). From GoF:

> Avoid coupling the sender of a request to its receiver by giving more than one object a chance to handle the request. Chain the receiving objects and pass the request along the chain until an object handles it.

Here's a barebones example that uses the names of business processes you've given:

```
// These all should be named something relevant to your domain
public interface IHandler
{
    void Handle(string request);
}

public class Handler
{
    protected IHandler successor;

    protected Handler(IHandler successor)
    {
        this.successor = successor;
    }

    protected virtual void Successor(string request)
    {
        successor?.Handle(request);
    }
}

public class Registration : Handler, IHandler
{
    public Registration(IHandler successor) 
        : base(successor) { }

    public void Handle(string request)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Registration handled request {request}");
        base.Successor(request);
    }
}

public class Enrollment : Handler, IHandler
{
    public Enrollment(IHandler successor) 
        : base(successor) { }

    public void Handle(string request)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Enrollment handled request {request}");
        base.Successor(request);
    }
}

public class Assessment : Handler, IHandler
{
    public Assessment(IHandler successor) 
        : base(successor) { }

    public void Handle(string request)
    {

        if (request.Equals("Bob", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bob failed assessment.");
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Assessment handled request {request}");
        base.Successor(request);
    }
}
```

and example use:

```
        // Consumers of this don't need to know anything more than it's an IHandler service
// Consumers of this don't need to know anything more than it's an IHandler service
IHandler noregistrationHandlers = new Assessment(new Enrollment(null));
// or Autofac
// builder.Register(c => new Assessment(c.Resolve<Enrollment>(null))).Named("NoRegistration");
// or your favorite IoC container
noregistrationHandlers.Handle("Smith");

IHandler registrationHandlers = new Registration(new Assessment(new Enrollment(null)));
// builder.Register(c => new Registration(c.Resolve<Assessment>(c.Resolve<Enrollment>(null)))).Named("Registration");
registrationHandlers.Handle("Bob");
```

Here's the takeaway on this - the consuming code (the usage example) *doesn't need to know anything* except the format to send the request to the handler. The fact that the constructors are invoked in the example is a matter of mere convenience for example's sake. You can very well have an MVC controller that depends on an `IHandler` but knows nothing else about it.

```
public class UserController
{
    private readonly IHandler handler;

    public UserController(IHandler handler)
    {
        if (handler == null) throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(handler));

        this.handler = handler; 
    }

    // ...

    public ActionResult Save(string id)
    { 
        handler(id);
    }
}
```